# Lists on the same column in Trello

Tags: trello

I'd like to know if I can put lists on the same vertical line in Trello. I couldn't do it but it would be pretty good for my work. Some lists don't need to be separated in different columns.

Answer (score 3):

**Update - 2014-07-29**

The Trello design is no longer responsive, i.e. it no longer resizes as windows shrink. Trello support, in Case FC2725939, told me it is by design:

> This actually is a change that we recently implemented because some Trello members were getting in to a weird state when they had their browser windows sized too small.

---

You don't mention what platform or browser, but the article [Building trello.com for multiple devices](http://blog.fogcreek.com/building-trello-com-for-multiple-devices/) describes how Trello is laid out, and so how you can control the layout.

So, if you create a narrow browser window, and/or increase the font size, it should eventually switch to a single column view.

**Edit**

Here is a series of screenshots, showing Trello in gradually narrower and narrower windows, showing how it rearranges its contents to fit the space available.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Doesn't work on Firefox 31.0.

Comment: @wassup You're right - and it doesn't work on IE11 either (both on Windows 7). It looks like something has changed in the design. The blog post I referenced doesn't have a comment feature, so I've sent feedback via http://help.trello.com/customer/portal/emails/new

Comment: @wassup Trello have confirmed that the design change was intentional - so I've added a note to the top of the answer - with the original text preserved for the record (and in case the behaviour ever gets reverted)

Answer (score 2):

You can also use this Chrome extension I've recently published: [Vertical Trello - Chrome Web Store](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/vertical-trello/aldklnbenbdgfgfbflalmlddkkndgnlc)